# Не могу обратиться к элементам массива, созданного добавлением элементов через AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Здравствуйте. У меня имеется JSON файл, который содержит массив объектов.
В JS скрипте я создаю пустой массив, чтобы потом, получая данный AJAX запросом, добавлять их в этот массив и работать уже с массивом. Добавить получается, но я не могу почему-то обращаться после этого к элементам массива. Мне выводится *undefinded*.

**JSON**

```
{
  "news": [
    {
      "photo": "./img/img-news/header-background.jpg",
      "article": "Проект «Краснодог»",
      "text": "Проверка текста, который я написал и составил 1."
    },
    {
      "photo": "",
      "article": "Проект «Форум добрых дел»",
      "text": "Сегодня я вам с радостью сообщаю, что работа выполнена!"
    }
  ]
}
```

**JS**

```
function News() {
    this.newsItems = [];
}

News.prototype.getItemsJson = function () {
    $.get({
       url: './news.json',
       dataType: "JSON",
       context: this,
       success: function (data) {
           // for (var key in data.news) {
           //     this.newsItems.push(data.news[key]);
           // }
           for (var i = 0; i < data.news.length; i++) {
               this.newsItems.push(data.news[i]);
           }
       }
    });
};

News.prototype.printArr = function () {
    console.log(this.newsItems);
    console.log(this.newsItems[0]);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var news = new News();
    news.getItemsJson();
    news.printArr();
});
```

Результат выполнения работы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Работает.

```js
var data = '{\
  "news": [\
    {\
      "photo": "./img/img-news/header-background.jpg",\
      "article": "Проект «Краснодог»",\
      "text": "Проверка текста, который я написал и составил 1."\
    },\
    {\
      "photo": "",\
      "article": "Проект «Форум добрых дел»",\
      "text": "Сегодня я вам с радостью сообщаю, что работа выполнена!"\
    }\
  ]\
}'; // <- json массив для проверки.


data = JSON.parse(data);// <- добавлена строка.

function News() {
    this.newsItems = [];
}
 News.prototype.getItemsJson = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.news.length; i++) {
               this.newsItems.push(data.news[i]);
           }
 }          
           
News.prototype.printArr = function () {
    console.log(this.newsItems);
    console.log(this.newsItems[0]);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var news = new News();
    news.getItemsJson();
    news.printArr();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Код с примером `$.get` :

```
$.get("./news.json", function(data){
  console.log(data);
}, "json");
```

Comment: А где AJAX запрос, который был в моем коде? Немного не догоняю.
data = JSON.parse(data); - что значит это строка?

Comment: Тут нельзя отправлять запросы по AJAX. Для примера взял готовый ответ от вашего AJAX и попробовал вывести. Работает.

Comment: JSON.parse – читает объекты из строки в формате JSON.

Comment: Всё-таки подскжаите, как подключить JSON файл к JS? Я делаю через $.getJSON, а в нем парсю, но у меня выдается ошибка "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Comment: Напишите мне пожалуйста в телеграмм @vokler. У меня какая-то путаница произошла в голове. Буду очень благодарен, если вы поможете :)